# Create XML schema to Restrict Attribute tag based upon value in Xml

Tags: wpf, xml, xsd

I have one xml in which i need to restrict one attribute tag based upon value of it. 
     Like in following xml file if value of attribute "permanent" is true than only its coming in xml

```
<Information >
<description>Worker information</description>
<A id="234" permanent="true" > 
    <name>xyz</name>
    <age>23</age> 
</A> 
<B id="244"> 
    <name>lkj</name>
    <age>27</age> 
</B>
<C id="204" permanent="true" > 
    <name>C</name>
    <age>27</age> 
</C>

</Information>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution
Make that attribute optional and assign "permanentFieldSpecified" bool property generated in designer true.